# Azure ML App - Complete Experince - Train automatically and Consume

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I played a bit around with Azure ML studio. So as I understand the process goes like this:

a) Create training experiment. Train it with data.

b) Create Scoring experiment. This will include the trained model from the training experiment. Expose this as a service to be consumed over REST.

Maybe a stupid question but what is the recommended way to get the complete experience like the one i get when I use an app like https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/amla/mba (Frequently Bought Together API built with Azure Machine Learning).

I mean the following:

a) Expose 2 or more services - one to train the model and the other to consume (test) the trained model.

b) User periodically sends training data to train the model

c) The trained model/models now gets saved available for consumption

d) User is now able to send a dataframe to get the predicted results.

Is there an additional wrapper that needs to be built?

If there is a link documenting this please point me to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure ML retraining API is designed to handle the workflow you describe:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-retrain-models-programmatically/

Hope this helps,

Roope - Microsoft Azure ML Team

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at [Azure Data Factory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/data-factory/).

I have written a [Custom Activity](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/) to do the same.

And used the logic to [retrain the model](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-retrain-models-programmatically/) in the custom activity.